# Delete multiple files from multiple zip archives

Tags: powershell

I have a list of files which I need to delete from multiple years' worth of monthly file archives.
there are about 400+ file names in a text file, and about 5 years of monthly archives, sorted into folders by year.

my script does a double loop, looking for each file in each archive and deleting it, but it's insaaaanely slow.
I'm looking for any suggestions of what I can do to improve my approach.  thanks!

```
set-alias rar "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

    $archives = get-childitem 'D:\Archive Data\APP_P\website\Document\exports\Exports Archive\Archive\2014exports'   -Recurse
    write-host $archives
    Get-Alias rar

    foreach ($archive in $archives ) {

    write-host $archive.Mode

    $exports = Get-Content C:\scripts\ScottTrade_cleanup.txt.txt
        foreach ($export in $exports){
        write-host $export
       rar d $archive.FullName $export -r

        }

    }
```

Comment: $exports = Get-Content C:\scripts\ScottTrade_cleanup.txt.txt could be done outside any loop I think

Comment: ForFiles /p "C:\My Folder" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file"

Comment: 7Z supports a `@listfile` so hand over the list of files to delete instead of iterating manually, which involves loading 7z.exe over and over again.

Comment: I think i am a little confused. You are trying to delete files inside zip files? Also what version of .net are you running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a minor performance issue with

```
$exports = Get-Content C:\scripts\ScottTrade_cleanup.txt.txt
```

Move that outside the loops

The big problem is that you are reloading a zip for every file you are seeking to delete. We need to fix this. Take your file that is a list of files, get rid of the inner loop and run this:

```
rar d $archive.FullName -r @FullListFilePathNameExtension
```

My first solution was to use the include switch (-i) with the delete, but Windows doesn't support command line over 8k.

Comment: So, if i'm supplying a full list of files to delete for each archive after the -r, then there's really no need for me to read in the list of files into the $exports variable.  right?

Comment: this almost works - except powershell seems to be unhappy with the @, and may be reading it as a declaration of an array.

set-alias rar "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

$archives = get-childitem 'd:\scripts'   -Recurse



foreach ($archive in $archives ) { rar d $archive.FullName @C:\scripts\ScottTrade_cleanup.txt }

Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:7 char:60

Comment: @llirik42 it should be like 400 times faster; report back on the improvement if you would please; I'm curious about the gain

Comment: I ran this against 3 rar files as a test, and it completed in just a few minutes.  it's a HUGE performance improvement! Though I cannot measure it exactly, I expect that something that would have taken a week+ to finish will be done in a couple hours